# how to set canvas background image tight full size in react

Tags: reactjs, canvas, mouseevent

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import correctTypo from "../../assets/correctTypo.png"
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

const styles = {
  position:'absolute',
  width:'2.5vw',
  height:'2.5vw',
  backgroundColor:'black',
}


export default function TypoComp() {

  // canvas 기본 설정
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [getCtx, setGetCtx] = useState(null);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // 배경 이미지 넣기
    const bgImg = new Image();
    bgImg.src = correctTypo;
    bgImg.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0,  1000, 1000);
    }
    
    setGetCtx(ctx);
  }, [])

  // Mouse Event 사용하여 그림그리기
  const [painting, setPainting] = useState(false);
  const drawFn = e => {
    let rect = canvas.getBoun
    const mouseX = e.nativeEvent.offsetX;
    const mouseY = e.nativeEvent.offsetY;
    if (!painting) {
      getCtx.beginPath();
      getCtx.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    } else {
      getCtx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
      getCtx.stroke();
    }
  }

  return (
    
    <Box className='typo'>
      <canvas
        width={1000}
        height={1000}
        style={{width:'100%'}}
        ref={canvasRef}
        onMouseDown={()=> setPainting(true)}
        onMouseUp={()=> setPainting(false)}
        onMouseMove={e => drawFn(e)}
        onMouseLeave={()=> setPainting(false)}>
        {/* <Draggable onDrag={handleDrag} onStop={handleStop}> */}
          <Box sx={{...styles, top:'31%', right:'21%',}}></Box>
        {/* </Draggable> */}
          <Box sx={{...styles, top:'52%', right:'80%',}}></Box>
          <Box sx={{...styles, top:'59%', right:'53%',}}></Box>
          <Box sx={{...styles, top:'80%', right:'47%',}}></Box>
<img className='samsung' src={correctTypo} width='100%' height='100%'/>
      </canvas>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

I made this code for drawing a line over the image file. I set background image of the canvas element and I want to make a line over the image. However, when I stretch the canvas element using `style={{width:'100%'}}`, it has a problem.
I have to make this canvas size be full to parent element because I have to consider the change of window size. However, when I stretch the width, the mouse position is not exact. Can anyone help me?

canvas resizing and mouse position problem.

Comment: could you post a runnable script (codesandbox example) to your question?